# How Can I Use the GET Method to Obtain a User's IP Address in Pure JS?

Tags: javascript

Hello this is my first question here. I'm really new to JS and i need a pure JS way to get the IP address of a web visitor and display it to him. How can i do it using GET and does anybody know why my code below will not work?

My aim is to get the info from http://ip-api.com/json

```
function goHome () {
    var xhr = XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", "http://ip-api.com/json", false);
    xhr.send();
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
        var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        alert(response.query);
    }
}
```

Comment: Looking at the Console in your browser's developer tools is a really good way to start figuring out why JS doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> var xhr = XMLHttpRequest();
> ```

XMLHttpRequest is a constructor function, you must call it with the `new` operator - like the example below:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution doesn't make use of the **GET** method but instead uses the **fetch** one - solution in pure js. I hope it helps ! Cheers!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Get user's IP</title>
    <style>
    body{
      background-color: black;
    }
        p, h1 {
            color: white;
      font-family: courier;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
  function json(url) {
      return fetch(url).then(res => res.json());
    }

    json(`https://api.ipify.org?format=json`).then(data => {
      console.log(data.ip);
      document.getElementById('userip').innerHTML = data.ip;
    });

    </script>

</head>

<body>


        <p style="text-align:center;font-size: 3em" id="userip"></p>

</body>

</html>
```

> EDIT
>
> It works if you also use this api: http://ip-api.com/json but you have
> to change data.ip => data.query - on stackoverflow the request gets
> blocked so i used the ipify.org api.

Answer (score -1):

This is an function with an async response. The easiest way to implement is using callbacks:

```
function goHome(cb){
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    var fnError = function(type){
        return function(){
            console.error('error', type, 'has ocurred');
            cb({error: type});
        }; 
    };
    var fnOK = function(evt){

        if (evt.currentTarget && evt.currentTarget.readyState === 4 && evt.currentTarget.status === 200) {
            try{
                var response = JSON.parse(evt.currentTarget.responseText);
                cb(null, response.query)
            }catch(err){
                fnError('parsing xhr failed')();
            }
        } else {
            fnError('xhr failed')();
        }
    }


    xhr.open("GET", 'http://ip-api.com/json', true);

    xhr.addEventListener('error', fnError('error') );
    xhr.addEventListener('abort', fnError('abort') );
    xhr.addEventListener('load', fnOK);
    xhr.send();
}
```

basic usage:

```
goHome(function(err, ip){
    if (err){
        console.error(err);
    } else {
        //do stuff
        console.log(JSON.stringify(ip));
    }
});
```

Comment: "This is an function with an async response." — No, it isn't. The OP set `async` to `false` when they called `open()`.

Comment: You are right, I copied that part from the question without paying good attention to it. It should be replaced by an async version of xhr. Now it has been corrected.